# How can I tell if a particular directory is connected to a remote machine?

Tags: command-line, nfs

I've found various ways to check if a particular directory is mounted under NFS ([here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/72223/8474), for example), but none of them seem to work on OS X. **How can I check if a particular directory is an NFS directory in the shell on a Mac?**

Answer (score 1):

The command `df` will include a list of all NFS shares, and their mount points. If a directory's path includes an NFS mount point, it stored on that machine.